# Efficient way of creating a sorted music library

Tags: c++, qt, sorting, vector, set

I'm trying to create an own music player/library in qt/c++.
What I've already done is scanning a folder for music files, reading the tags of the music file with *taglib*, creating a `Track` struct from the file, and putting the `Track` inside a `vector` of Tracks. Here's the code I have so far:

This scans the folder:

```
void LibraryScanner::scanFolder (std::string scanFolder) {
    if (filesystem::exists (scanFolder) && filesystem::is_directory (scanFolder))
    {
        filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator recursiveIterator (scanFolder);

        for (const auto& entry : filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator (scanFolder)) {
            std::wstring path = entry.path().wstring ();
            if (hasEnding (path, L".flac") || hasEnding (path, L".wav") || hasEnding (path, L".alac") || hasEnding (path, L".mp3") || hasEnding (path, L".m4a") || hasEnding (path, L".wma") || hasEnding (path, L".opus") || hasEnding (path, L".ogg") || hasEnding (path, L".aiff")) { ///TODO: ignore capital letters
                scanFile (path);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

each audio file is then further processed in the scanFile method:

```
void LibraryScanner::scanFile (const std::wstring filePath)
{
    Track track = Track ();
    TagLib::FileRef f (filePath.c_str());
    if(!f.isNull()){
        track.filePath = filePath.c_str ();
        track.Title = f.tag()->title().toWString();
        track.Artists = f.tag()->artist().toWString();
        tracks.push_back (track);
    }else {
        std::wcout <<  "File is null." << '\n';
    }
}
```

Each track is put into this vector:

```
std::vector<Track> tracks;
```

and here's the `Track` struct:

```
#pragma once
#include<string>

struct Track{
    std::wstring filePath, Title, Artists;
};
```

So now, I want my music player to kinda work like this:

[music player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKMXm.png)

[sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiUsC.png)

There's a list of artists which is alphabetically sorted (left side of the picture), and each artist has different tracks (right side) which are also sorted by their album.

I should also note that each Track can have multiple artists, so 2 artists could share the same tracks.

But also, I can not only sort by Artist, but also by Album or other tags (you can see that in the second picture). And switching between sorting by Artist/Album is instantly in this program.

So how do I implement something like this, which is also very performant, in my own program?
I was thinking of presorting everything during scanning. So after I put each `Track` inside the `vector` of Tracks, I create a `vector` or `Set` of Artists, and each artists contains tracks or albums. So I've created an `Artist` struct like this:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include "Track.h"
#include <string>
class Artist
{
public:
    Artist (std::wstring artistName);
    ~Artist ();
    std::wstring artistName;
    std::vector<Track*> tracks;
};
```

Since multiple artists can share tracks, I thought making the tracks vector only contain pointers of `Track` would be a good idea.

So my presorted list of artists would be an `std::vector<Artist> artists;`, and each Artist contains its own tracks with the same Artist tag (which I can sort by album later on).

Then, if I wanna sort by albums, I have another vector like this: `std::vector<Album> albums;` with each `Album` containing its own tracks.
And if I want to switch the sorting mode, I just change which vector is displayed as a list.

My question is, if there's a more performant/efficient way to do all that.
This looks like it will use a lot of memory and will take lots of time to sort, because I will basically sort multiple times after scanning (for each sorting mode one vector).

Also, I need to check if there are any duplicate artists. Plus, each track/artist/album should have an own cover image which I want to display. I need to check those for duplicates too

So this way will use lots of resources.
I'd be very thankful if someone knows a way how to efficiently do this, and maybe has some code samples too.
And if anyone knows a more performant way to scan folders for files or what I did in the code snippets I posted, that would help too.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you want to use sqlite for your data.

Comment: *Since multiple artists can share tracks* -- Suggest using `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Track>>` instead of `std::vector<Track*>`

Answer (score 1):

**Use Database:**
 Use database  like mysql to store all the audio information and metadata. The sorting and duplication checking will be lot easier to implement.

**Categorize Audio Files:**
 Categorize the files into separate folders depending on genres.If the number of audio files are huge, you can load only a page at a time, after sorting, and then  proceed to the subsequent pages.

**Use smart_pointer in the Playlist:**
      Use std::shared_ptr to load from the media folder to the playlist. This will reduce further comsumption of memory. For example if a commercial is inserted between an audio file, the two parts may still have identical fields.

Comment: I think sqlite would be a better choice than mysql in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to look into model view controller framework classes like https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html

They have concept of proxymodels over models based on in memory or file system or sqlite based data and these proxy models have features like sorting and filtering.

creating GUi is also automatic becuase you just need to connect the list view or tree view with proxy models.

These are highly optimized models and sorting and filtering is also very efficient with lesser code.